# How should Model Validation be implemented in Loopback 4?

Tags: typescript, model, loopback, v4l2loopback

I'm pretty new to Loopback 4 framework, and I'm trying to use it for a small project that needs to connect data from different kinds of databases and services. One of the main reasons I'm using version 4 is because of Typescript and also because it supports ES7 features (async/await), which I really appreciate. Still, I have no idea how to implement model validation, at least not like Loopback v3 supports.

I've tried to implement custom validation on model constructors, but it looks like a really bad pattern to follow.

```
import {Entity, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';

@model()
export class Person extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    required: true,
  })
  id: number;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;

  @property({
    type: 'date',
    required: true,
  })
  birthDate: string;

  @property({
    type: 'number',
    required: true,
  })
  phone: number;

  constructor(data: Partial<Person>) {
    if (data.phone.toString().length > 10) throw new Error('Phone is not a valid number');
    super(data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LB4 uses ajv module to validate the incoming request data based on your model metadata. So, you can do a it using jsonSchema as mentioned below.

```
export class Person extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    required: true,
  })
  id: number;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;

  @property({
    type: 'date',
    required: true,
  })
  birthDate: string;

  @property({
    type: 'number',
    required: true,
    jsonSchema: {
      maximum: 9999999999,
    },
  })
  phone: number;

  constructor(data: Partial<Person>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

Hope that works.
Refer to the answer to a similar question on LB4 repo [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2735#issuecomment-483425305) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Samy! It really helped me a lot! Now I'm stuck with custom validation, this cpf property is an ID with a custom validation rule (its basically an ID that the Brazilian government gives you, similar to US IDs). Any ideas on how to add keywords on Ajv module? I tried to follow these instructions (https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/CUSTOM.md), importing the Ajv module on the model file.

Comment: If you can share the code you are trying with (in a repo or stackblitz), I may be able to help you better. As far as I can see, ajv keywords should work.

Comment: Did you try with 'pattern' in jsonSchema ?

Comment: How do you implement validation rules that can't be expressed using JSON Schema?

Comment: I do it at controller method.

Comment: Answer is slightly incorrect, should be maximum: 9999999999